# How do I fix the twist mechanism on a blind?

Tags: blinds

As you can see from the image below the twisting mechanism which holds the longer stick to adjust the angle of the blind as broken.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed, either by fitting a new twisting mechanism in or a DIY hack?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would repair this by fitting a short piece of aluminum, copper or brass tubing over the nubbin of the shaft. This can be glued in place using epoxy. Before installation the end of the tubing can be worked to make a new end to engage the wand. The simplest *(working with copper is especially nice)* way would be to squeeze the end of the tubing flat. Then trim the corners of the flattened section to a rounded end profile. Finally make a hole in the end that can take a ring linkage from the adjustment wand.

I was going to draw a picture of the idea but it was faster to just make a sample of the proposal. Just choose the tubing with an inner diameter that is close to the size of the nubbin. The hole for the linkage gets drilled through the flattened end. Before trying to apply the epoxy in the tube do use a Q-Tip dipped in isopropyl alcohol to clean away any possible oil film left from the manufacturing of the tubing.

[image]

Comment: +1 for answering with a hammer not just with a keyboard. Well OK a vice probably.

Comment: How about I tell you it was just a tool as in this picture: http://www.irwin.com/uploads/cms/image/press-images/VISE-GRIP_GrooveLock.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The part showing has a gear on the inside of the header. You might have to swap out the whole mechanism if you can get a replacement if you knew the manufacturer and they offered parts.

A repair might not be too hard. I would cut off the broken end leaving as much rod as possible. Then attach a u-shaped shackle to the bottom that mates with another u shaped shackle on the lower rod. They can be attached with a small screw or bolt in a hole drilled through the shackles and the rods.

[image: shackle]

The shackles can be bought from a marine supply shop or made from thin pieces of metal (steel or brass). You also might find some fittings tha could be bent into these shapes in a craft store.

Comment: I'd be worried that the hole drilled through the fairly thin plastic dowels would fracture the dowels.

Comment: The alternative, a bit more complicated, is to put a metal tube over the dowels (as Michael Karas suggests in another answer) and attach the shackle through the tube and dowel. But the original appears to be a plastic dowel with a good bit of its cross section removed, so a small hole through the entire body is not likely to break it up.